# How do I group Accounts/Contacts by $ amount of all won opportunities this year?

Tags: custom-field, formula-field, picklist, dependent-picklist

My company wants to automatically group Accounts/Contacts by ranges of money spent this year.

For example:

Top Buyer (won opportunities totaling >$25k)
Medium Buyer (won opportunities totaling $10k-25k)
Low Buyer (won opportunities totaling

There's already a field for "Total Purchases This Year ($)". How do I get that field to then automatically update another picklist field with the Top, Medium, Low options? Is there a way to then remove the field data after no won opportunities in the past year?

For example, if someone makes a $1000 purchase, I would like a way for that contact to automatically be designated as a "Low Buyer", but to be designated null after one year of no action.

Comment: What type of field is "Total Purchases This Year"?

Comment: @JaredT Currency. The description is: "The total amount of won Opportunities related to this Account, closed in the current year or fiscal year."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Roll-Up Summary field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm) on `Account` to calculate SUM of Amounts, and set a Filter Criteria for `CloseDate` (you can't use [Relative Date Values](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_dates.htm) here, so would have to setup greater than and less than of actual year start and end dates), and also for `Closed Won` `Status`.
After this you have to create a formula field like:

```
IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 25000,
 'Top Buyer',
 IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 10000,
  'Medium Buyer',
  'Low Buyer'
 )
)
```

One downside is that you have to ***update year start/end dates once a year***, but this is not that much of work at all.

Comment: Thanks - this is just what I need. Where am I going wrong with this formula syntax?

` IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 24999,
 'Top Buyer', 
    IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 9999,
      'Mid Buyer', 
        IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 4999,
          'Low Buyer' )
)) `

Comment: ` IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 24999,
 'Top Buyer', 
    IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 9999,
      'Mid Buyer', 
        IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 4999,
          'Low Buyer' )
)) `

Comment: You'd better go with `MyYearRollUp__c >= 25000` if you want them to be inclusive

Comment: IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 25000,
 'Top Buyer',
 IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 10000,
  'Medium Buyer',
  IF( MyYearRollUp__c > 5000,
   'Low Buyer',
   ''
  )
 )
)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [declarative lookup roll up summaries tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) allows for relative date filters in roll ups

[This blog post](http://succeedwithsalesforce.com/going-beyond-native-roll-up-summary-fields/) highlights a use case using relative date filters (example no 3)

I would suggest testing that tool, the developer is a MVP and the CTO (or something along those lines) of financial force, so it's pretty loaded w awesome sauce.